# Mysql error with union and in clause

Tags: mysql, sql, union, where-clause

A mysql query for a search with the following sql

```
SELECT societa.nome, documenti.document, soieditor.nominativo, document_revision.* 
FROM document_revision 
        JOIN societa ON societa.id = document_revision.societa 
        JOIN documenti ON documenti.id = document_revision.tipo_document 
        JOIN soieditor ON soieditor.id = document_revision.createdby 
        WHERE document_revision.id in(
        (
    (SELECT id from document_revision WHERE `description` LIKE '%f%' OR `tag` LIKE '%f%' OR `lingua` LIKE '%f%') 
    union 
    (SELECT doc_rev_id from document_metadata WHERE `met_key` LIKE '%f%' OR `meta_value` LIKE '%f%') 
    union 
    (SELECT doc_id from document_files WHERE `file_name` LIKE '%f%')))
```

gives me following error  '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'union (SELECT doc_rev_id from document_metadata WHERE `met_key` LIKE '%fwdfdfdfd' at line 1'

please help me to trouble shoot the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT societa.nome, 
    documenti.document, 
    soieditor.nominativo, 
    document_revision.* 
FROM document_revision 
    JOIN societa ON societa.id = document_revision.societa 
    JOIN documenti ON documenti.id = document_revision.tipo_document 
    JOIN soieditor ON soieditor.id = document_revision.createdby 
WHERE document_revision.id in
(
    SELECT id as ii
    from document_revision 
    WHERE description LIKE '%f%' OR tag LIKE '%f%' OR lingua LIKE '%f%' 

    union 

    SELECT doc_rev_id as ii
    from document_metadata 
    WHERE met_key LIKE '%f%' OR meta_value LIKE '%f%'

    union 

    SELECT doc_id as ii
    from document_files 
    WHERE `file_name` LIKE '%f%'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an alias on the first subquery of your union chain, in this way:

```
SELECT societa.nome, documenti.document, soieditor.nominativo, document_revision.*
FROM document_revision 
JOIN societa ON societa.id = document_revision.societa 
JOIN documenti ON documenti.id = document_revision.tipo_document 
JOIN soieditor ON soieditor.id = document_revision.createdby 
WHERE document_revision.id in(
(
    (SELECT id as myid -- alias named your output field
    from document_revision
    WHERE `description` LIKE '%f%' OR `tag` LIKE '%f%' OR `lingua` LIKE '%f%')
    union
    (SELECT doc_rev_id
    from document_metadata WHERE `met_key` LIKE '%f%' OR `meta_value` LIKE '%f%')
    union
    (SELECT doc_id from document_files WHERE `file_name` LIKE '%f%')
)
)
```